# Play! framework referential integrity contraint on delete

Tags: java, hibernate, model, playframework, associations

I created some Model object to represent a company with several clients, and an invoice object that consists of a company and client combination and several invoice lines. I have created the following Model objects:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Model {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
    public Set<Client> clients;
}

@Entity
public class Client extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Company company;
}

@Entity
public class Invoice extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Company company;
    @ManyToOne
    public Client client;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="invoice", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<InvoiceLine> invoiceLines;
}

@Entity
public class InvoiceLine extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Invoice invoice;
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void testModels() {
    Client client = createClient();
    Company company = createCompany();
    company.clients = new HashSet<Client>();
    company.clients.add(client);
    company.save();

    Invoice invoice = createInvoice(client, company);
    InvoiceLine invoiceLine1 = createInvoiceLine(invoice);
    InvoiceLine invoiceLine2 = createInvoiceLine(invoice);
    Set<InvoiceLine> invoiceLines = new HashSet<InvoiceLine>();
    invoiceLines.add(invoiceLine1);
    invoiceLines.add(invoiceLine2);
    invoice.invoiceLines = invoiceLines;
    invoice.save();

    Company retrievedCompany = Company.find("byName", company.name).first();
    assertNotNull(retrievedCompany);
    assertEquals(1, retrievedCompany.clients.size());
    assertEquals(2, InvoiceLine.count());

    assertEquals(1, Invoice.deleteAll());
    assertNull(Invoice.all());
    assertNull(InvoiceLine.all());
```

}

When running a test that creates an invoice with two invoice lines, and try to delete this invoice, I get the following error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: 
>   "FK3004B0A1F4110EF6: PUBLIC.INVOICELINE FOREIGN KEY(INVOICE_ID) REFERENCES >PUBLIC.INVOICE(ID)"; 
>   SQL statement: delete from Invoice [23003-149]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add the code of the test to see the steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this with `invoice.delete()`? The problem is that `deleteAll()` doesn't cascade the delete operation.

`deleteAll()` uses a `javax.persistence.Query` internally, while `delete()` uses the `EntityManager`'s `remove()` method. The cascading in JPA is handled by JPA and not by the database, and JPA does not cascade bulk deletes like the one executed by `deleteAll()`.
[Check this link for more info on bulk delete/update](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_bulk_ops).

Also: adding the InvoiceLine entities to `Invoice` is redundant if you are already setting `Invoice` as the parent in `createInvoiceLine()`. Just do `invoice.refresh()` before executing the asserts.

Maybe the following unit test clears things up.
The `Parent1` is like your `Invoice`. While `Child1` is like your `InvoiceLine`.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.junit.*;
import play.test.*;
import models.*;

public class Parent1Test extends UnitTest {

    public Parent1 p;
    public Child1 c1;
    public Child1 c2;
    public Child1 c3;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Fixtures.deleteAllModels();

        p = new Parent1();
        c1 = new Child1();
        c2 = new Child1();
        c3 = new Child1();
    }

    public void byAddingParentToChilds() {
        c1.parent = p;
        c2.parent = p;
        c3.parent = p;

        c1.save();
        c2.save();
        c3.save();
        p.refresh();
    }

    @Test
    public void testByAddingParentToChilds() {
        byAddingParentToChilds();
        assertEquals(p.id, c1.parent.id);
        assertEquals(3, Child1.count());
    }

    public void byAddingChildsToParent() {
        p.childs = new ArrayList<Child1>();
        p.childs.add(c1);
        p.childs.add(c2);
        p.childs.add(c3);
        p.save();
    }

    @Test
    public void testByAddingChildsToParent() {
        // By adding childs
        byAddingChildsToParent();

        c1.refresh();
        assertEquals(3, Child1.count());
        // This will be null, because you added the childs to the 
        // parent while the childs are the owning side of the 
        // relation.
        assertNull(c1.parent);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeletingAfterAddingParentToChilds() {
        byAddingParentToChilds();
        p.delete();
        assertEquals(0, Parent1.count());
        assertEquals(0, Child1.count());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeletingAfterAddingChildsToParent() {
        byAddingChildsToParent();
        p.delete();
        assertEquals(0, Parent1.count());
        assertEquals(0, Child1.count());
    }

    @Test(expected=PersistenceException.class)
    public void testDeleteAllAfterAddingParentToChilds() {
        byAddingParentToChilds();
        // The cascading doesn't work for deleteAll() so this line
        // will throw an exception because the child elements still
        // reference the parent.
        assertEquals(1, Parent1.deleteAll());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteAllAfterAddingChildsToParent() {
        byAddingChildsToParent();
        assertEquals(1, Parent1.deleteAll());
        assertEquals(0, Parent1.count());
        // Again the cascading doesn't work for deleteAll()
        assertEquals(3, Child1.count());
    }

}
```

Comment: One question, in method byAddingParentToChilds() you first save the parent then the children followed by a refresh of the parent. This seems to be somewhat redundant because a save of the parent (assuming the persist is cascaded) should be enough to reach the same, am I correct?

Comment: Correct, and fixed in answer :)

Comment: But the refresh is needed because the childs add themselves to the parent and update the database (by saving), but the parents state still has to be updated from the database.

Comment: If you want to save only once it's best to create an `addChild()` to the parent that adds the child and sets it's parent. This way you can just call `save()` once on the parent. Which is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete all Invoices but there are still some InvoiceLines linked to it.

Try deleting the invoice lines first and thenthe Invoices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem seems to be related to JPA instead of Play! framework. The behaviour I want is that invoiceLines are automatically deleted when the invoice the are related to is deleted. I was thinking that by adding CascadeType.ALL and orphanRemoval set to true, I would get this behaviour but instead I get an integrity constraint violation whe deleting the invoice behore deleting the invoiceLines.